# Generating hidden box collider between two game objects in unity

Tags: unity, mathematics

I'm trying to implement flappy bird clone using unity. I'm creating two obstacles at random y position. I would like to create a hidden box collider game object between them, but I'm struggling with the math. I want the box collider to be generated between both game objects so that I use it to detect if the bird has passed the two obstacles.

Here is how I generate the obstacles

// function called by InvokeRepeating function

```
void CreateObstacle(){
        // generating random upper pipe position
        float randomPos = 4f-(4f-0.8f-pipeHole)*Random.value;
        // adding upper pipe to stage
        GameObject upperPipe = (GameObject)Instantiate(pipeObject);
        // setting upper pipe position
        upperPipe.transform.position = new Vector2(4f,randomPos);
        // adding lower pipe to stage
        GameObject lowerPipe = (GameObject)Instantiate(pipeObject);
        // setting lower pipe position
        lowerPipe.transform.position = new Vector2(4f,randomPos-pipeHole-4.8f);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden" box collider?

Comment: a game object that is not seen, its just acting as a box collider

Comment: Make a prefab that holds your empty gameobject + collider (+ a script probably). Middle position will be (upperPipe.transform.position + lowerPipe.transform.postion) / 2 . Then scale your trigger object based on the difference in position: (upperPipe.transform.position - lowerPipe.transform.postion).

Comment: scale it in which axis ?

Comment: Depends on which axis your pipes are aligned on. The difference in position will have a value of 0 for each axis that are aligned, you won't want to scale these. Scale it on each axis that has a difference != 0 (for example, try scale += difference/2 , and if you are using default scaling for everything the math might just work in your favor)

Answer (score 1):

why not make a prefab with 3 gameobjects with a trigger in the middle and you spawn the complete prefab  should be much easier

Answer (score 0):

You need to create emtpy gameobject and add colliders to it. Also, check the istrigger? checkbox. because, a normal collider will not allow the bird to pass through

Comment: what are the math

Comment: No maths. You just set it trigger. Then, to update score after the bird has crossed it, refer to OnTriggerExit2D()